# Can't connect to SQL Server in Docker container

Tags: sql-server, macos, docker

I can connect to SQL Server in a Docker container using...

```
Docker exec -it 93fc /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P Password$$123
```

But I can't connect if I plug the same details into RazorSQL.

i.e. localhost with SA and Password$$123

What step am I missing?

This is the run command...

```
Docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e SA_PASSWORD=Password$$123 -p 1433:1433 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

This is a connection string I've tried from a test running in Visual Studio...

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=master;User=sa;Password=Password$$123;
```

I think it can find the SQL Server but for some reason it can't login with SA.

Even this running from Windows doesn't work...

```
sqlcmd -S 192.168.10.79,1433 -U SA -P Password$$123
```

This problem goes away if I update the password using...

```
ALTER LOGIN SA WITH PASSWORD='Pa$$word123'
```

So I can connect to SQL Server inside the container using the initial password and then if I change the password I can connect externally.

How can the password determine if an external connection works?

If I enter `env` in the console, I get...

```
MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Password14961123
```

I presume that was auto generated.

Comment: That command runs `sqlcmd` inside the container. Add the command you run the sql container to your question.

Comment: @DanGuzman I've updated the question.

Comment: I wanted to make sure you had the default port mapped to the host. You should be able to connect specifying localhost in this case. I don't know RazorSQL but it might help if you add your connection string.

Comment: I've added a connection string. This connection string works if I point it at Windows running in Parallels.

Comment: I think SA_PASSWORD=Password$$123 in the docker run command needs to be in single quotes, same as 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y', like so:  `Docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Password$$123' -p 1433:1433 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux`